# How to compare user date with system date in c++?

Tags: c++, date

I  have taken in date from the user in DD/MM/YEAR formate but I want to compare it with system date and want to know whether the date entered by the user is in future or past !!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main ()
{      
    char date [10],sysdate[10];
    cout<<"enter Date";           
    cin>>date;                   //for taking date from user
    _strdate(sysdate);      //for getting system date(given in DD/MM/YY    
    cout<< sysdate;        //prints system date    
}
```

Comment: If you're writing C++, it's not C.

Comment: The C++ `chrono` facility does not appear to provide any support for dealing with years, months, and days. You can use the C `mktime()` function.

Comment: It is often OS specific. On POSIX systems consider [strptime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) & [strftime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) etc....

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing strictly with date strings (instead of date`time_t`timestamps or date`tm`structures), then you can directly compare date strings of the format `"YY/MM/DD"` to determine whether one comes before or after the other.

The format you are using (`"DD/MM/YY"`) does not allow this kind of direct string comparison.

Comment: But 'sydate' gives system date in DD/MM/YY format so how can i change that?

Comment: You could rearrange the digits within the `sysdate` value to create a new string, and use that one for the comparison.

Comment: how do i compare it even after rearranging it in YY/DD/MM?

Comment: Using `std::strcmp()` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Watch this example then it wont be hard to 
compare user date  with system date

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
   // current date/time based on current system
   time_t now = time(0);


   tm *ltm = localtime(&now);

   // print various components of tm structure.
   cout << "Year: "<< 1900 + ltm->tm_year << endl;
   cout << "Month: "<< 1 + ltm->tm_mon<< endl;
   cout << "Day: "<<  ltm->tm_mday << endl;

  }
```